# ScalaTest thrownBy testing exception message

Tags: scala, scalatest

To test if my code is throwing expected exception I use the following syntax:

```
  an [IllegalArgumentException] should be thrownBy(Algorithms.create(degree))
```

is there any way to test if thrown exception contains expected message like:

```
  an [IllegalArgumentException(expectedMessage)] should be thrownBy(Algorithms.create(degree)) -- what doesn't compile
```

?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Documentation](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers):

```
the [ArithmeticException] thrownBy 1 / 0 should have message "/ by zero"
```

and using that example:

```
 the [IllegalArgumentException] thrownBy(Algorithms.create(degree)) should have message expectedMessage
```

Comment: How would I check for a substring of the message? Assign the result of "the ... thrownBy ... " to a val, and then use regular matchers?

Comment: If you want to assert on a substring, you can:
```(the [ArithmeticException] thrownBy 1 / 0).getMessage should include ("zero")```

Answer (score 8):

Your syntax for checking the message is wrong. As an alternative to what bjfletcher suggested, you can also use the following, as per the documentation:

1. Capture the exception and assign it to a val

`val thrown = the [IllegalArgumentException] thrownBy Algorithms.create(degree)`

2. Use the val to inspect its contents. E.g.:

`thrown.getMessage should equal ("<whatever the message is")`

I personally like the first alternative introduced by bjfletcher more, since it is more compact. But capturing the exception itself, gives you more possibilities to inspect its contents.